# insert row to multiindex dataframe so that it is grouped under the correct index level

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have this multi-index data frame:

```
                    Item Purchased  Cost
Location    Name        
Store 1     Chris   Dog Food        22.5
            Kevyn   Kitty Litter    2.5
Store 2     Vinod   Bird Seed       5.0
```

and I can append a new row to it like this:

```
df = df.append(pd.Series(data={'Cost': 3.00, 'Item Purchased': 'Kitty Food'}, name=('Store 2', 'Kevyn')))
```

and the dataframe looks like this:

```
                    Item Purchased  Cost
Location    Name        
Store 1     Chris   Dog Food       22.5
            Kevyn   Kitty Litter    2.5
Store 2     Vinod   Bird Seed       5.0
            Kevyn   Kitty Food      3.0
```

But if the store value is Store 1, and not the Store 2, which is the last store, then the new data is (surprise!) appended to the end, and is not grouped with data for Store 1.

```
df = df.append(pd.Series(data={'Cost': 4.50, 'Item Purchased': 'Dog Food'}, name=('Store 1', 'Doug')))
```

and dataframe looks like this:

```
                    Item Purchased  Cost
Location    Name        
Store 1     Chris   Dog Food        22.5
            Kevyn   Kitty Litter    2.5
Store 2     Vinod   Bird Seed       5.0
            Kevyn   Kitty Food      3.0
Store 1     Doug    Dog Food        4.5
```

Is there a method other than append that would insert the new row under the 'Store1' index without appending 'Store1' to the end of df?
Thank you.

Comment: why not use after sort_index ?

Comment: Thank you! Per your suggestion `df.sort_index(level=0)` did it.